# Convert digits extracted by substring match to Years in PostgreSQL 11.0

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, date

I have following table in PostgreSQL 11.0

```
min age      max age
1 Month      12 Months
1 Year       16 Years
1 Day        365 Days
365 Days     369 Days
N/A          N/A
NULL         NULL
```

I would like to convert the values to year. I am extracting the string after the digit and check if it is 'years', 'months' or 'days' and then convert the digit before the string to year.

I tried following query:

```
update tbl
set min_age = 
        case 
                when substring(min_age, '^\d+\s(.*)') ~* 'Month'
                then abs(substring(min_age, '^(\d+)\s.*')/12)
                when substring(min_age, '^\d+\s(.*)') ~* 'Months'
                then abs(substring(min_age, '^(\d+)\s.*')/12)
                when substring(min_age, '^\d+\s(.*)') ~* 'Day'
                then abs(substring(min_age, '^(\d+)\s.*')/365)
                when substring(min_age, '^\d+\s(.*)') ~* 'Days'
                then abs(substring(min_age, '^(\d+)\s.*')/365)
                when substring(min_age, '^\d+\s(.*)') ~* 'Year'
                then abs(substring(min_age, '^(\d+)\s.*'))
                when substring(min_age, '^\d+\s(.*)') ~* 'Years'
                then abs(substring(min_age, '^(\d+)\s.*'))
        end ;

update tbl
set max_age = case
                when substring(min_age, '^\d+\s(.*)') ~* 'Month'
                then abs(substring(min_age, '^(\d+)\s.*')/12)
                when substring(min_age, '^\d+\s(.*)') ~* 'Months'
                then abs(substring(min_age, '^(\d+)\s.*')/12)
                when substring(min_age, '^\d+\s(.*)') ~* 'Day'
                then abs(substring(min_age, '^(\d+)\s.*')/365)
                when substring(min_age, '^\d+\s(.*)') ~* 'Days'
                then abs(substring(min_age, '^(\d+)\s.*')/365)
                when substring(min_age, '^\d+\s(.*)') ~* 'Year'
                then abs(substring(min_age, '^(\d+)\s.*'))
                when substring(min_age, '^\d+\s(.*)') ~* 'Years'
                then abs(substring(min_age, '^(\d+)\s.*'))
           end
```

Expected output is:

```
min age       max age
0             1
1             16
0             1
1             1
N/A           N/A
NULL          NULL
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Postgres has powerful interval functions. I think that a `cast` and `justify_interval()` might *just work* here:

```
select
    extract(year from justify_interval(min_age::interval)) min_age,   
    extract(year from justify_interval(max_age::interval)) max_age
from tbl
```

**[Demo on DB  Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=84cf9a806c60ff2266c9c7e8d5dea61a)**:

```
min_yr | max_yr
:----- | :-----
0      | 1     
1      | 16    
0      | 1     
1      | 1
```

Comment: @GMB Awesome solution!! Can the suggested query handle null values or another string like N/A. Table is updated for clarity.

Comment: @rshar: this will properl handle `null` values. As for `'N/A'`, this cannot be converted to an interval, so you would need some kind of conditional expression like `nullif(min_age, 'N/A')`.

Comment: @GMB I tried following query with no success.                                                            `                                                                                                                         update tbl                                                                                                                 set min_age = case  
                                when nullif(min_age, 'N/A') then 'N/A'
                                else extract(year from justify_interval(eligibility_minimum_age::interval))
                              END ;`

Comment: @GMB Could you please suggest modification in the above query (I am a newbie so sorry for a basic query)?

Comment: @rshar: I would just use `extract(year from justify_interval(nullif(min_age, 'N.A')::interval))`. This yields `null` for `'N/A'`, which seems more sensible to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can get all the values you need:

```
select split_part(min_age, " ", 1) as min_age_value, split_part(min_age, " ", 2) as min_age_unit, split_part(max_age, " ", 1) as max_age_value, split_part(max_age, " ", 2) as max_age_unit
from tbl;
```

Now, you can use the above as a substring and use case-when for min_age_unit and max_age_unit in the outer query, evaluating it to 1, 12 or 365 respectively and multiplying it with the actual value.